# Add argument to named function handler

Tags: javascript

I need to keep `checkZipValidHandler` a named function so I can remove the event listener later on (can not remove event listener with a anon function).

But I also need to pass in an argument named `origin` along with the event object. I don't want to apply any attributes to the HTML to attach to the event object.

How can I do this and still keep it a named function?

```
const checkZipValidHandler = function(e, origin) {
    console.log(origin);
    const zipInput = document.querySelector('.f-zipcode-no-inventory');
    const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.f-search-button-no-inventory');

    checkZipValid(e, zipInput.value, chooseBtn, origin);
}(origin);

const addEventListeners = (origin) => {
    const zipInput = document.querySelector('.f-zipcode-no-inventory');
    const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.f-search-button-no-inventory');

    chooseBtn.addEventListener('click', validateRetryHandler);
    zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkZipValidHandler.bind(origin));
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Having additional formal parameters won't hurt anything.

Comment: `e`  is getting clobbered and is showing the url rather than the actual event object.

Comment: So first you have no named functions in your code, the first line is assigning the call of an anonymous function to your `checkZipValidHandler` variable. Secondly, why are you appending the function call to your variable when your function is not returning anything ?

Comment: Also, your declaration *invokes* the function; that's a big part of why your code won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First thing.**

`checkZipValidHandler.bind(origin)` creates a new function. So this way (`zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkZipValidHandler.bind(origin));`) you won't be able to remove the event listener later.

**Second thing.**

`bind` takes the context as the first argument, and arguments to bind as the following ones.

**Third thing.**

When you bind an argument to the function you should expect it to be the first argument to catch after the bound function had been invoked.

And here we go:

```
const checkZipValidHandler = (origin, e) => {
  console.log(origin)
  const zipInput = document.querySelector('.f-zipcode-no-inventory');
  const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.f-search-button-no-inventory');

  checkZipValid(e, zipInput.value, chooseBtn, origin);
};

const addEventListeners = (origin) => {
  const zipInput = document.querySelector('.f-zipcode-no-inventory');
  const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.f-search-button-no-inventory');

  const checkZipValidHandlerBound = checkZipValidHandler.bind(null, origin);

  zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkZipValidHandlerBound);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `origin` as second parameter to `.bind()`

```
const checkZipValidHandler = function(origin, e) {
  console.log(origin)
  const zipInput = document.querySelector('.f-zipcode-no-inventory');
  const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.f-search-button-no-inventory');

  checkZipValid(e, zipInput.value, chooseBtn, origin);
};

const addEventListeners = (origin) => {
  const zipInput = document.querySelector('.f-zipcode-no-inventory');
  const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.f-search-button-no-inventory');

  zipInput.addEventListener('keyup', checkZipValidHandler.bind(zipInput, origin));
};
```

Comment: Also, note that `.bind()` will return a new function, and *that's* the function for which a reference needs to be maintained in order to later be able to remove the event listener.

Comment: Excellent! Never thought of passing in the actual `zipInput` as the first arg to bind. Thanks!

Comment: For learning....why was it necessary to revers the arg order `origin, e` in `const checkZipValidHandler = function(origin, e) {}`?

Comment: @dman because the browser will pass the event reference to your function regardless of how it was declared. When you pre-bind a parameter with `.bind()`, those will appear as actual arguments *before* whatever is passed in by the browser (before the event reference).

Comment: @Pointy The code would need to re-written to define the bound function and identifier that does not exist outside of scope of function which attaches event